# Executing a Node.js script to send a Twilio message from a client side button click

Tags: node.js, vue.js, twilio

I am looking to have a button on my web application query a MongoDB and send out a text message to the appropriate individuals based on the result of that query.

The issue I am having is in testing. I can't figure out a way to have the button on the client side run the node.js file on the server side.

Node.js: v8.9.4

Vue.js: 2.5.13

Express: 4.13.3

EDIT:

I've been able to get the nodejs script to run on its own. I just don't know how to call it from the client side

EDIT 2:

Main.js

```
// Dependencies
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var busboy = require('connect-busboy');
var cors = require('cors');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Configuration
var config = require('./config');
var twilio = require('twilio');
// Database
mongoose.connect(config.database);
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function(){
    console.log('Connected to database');
});

var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

// Setup middleware
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser(config.sessionSecret));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
app.use(busboy());
app.use(cors({
    origin: true,
    credentials: true
}));
app.get('/session',function(req){
    twilio.notifyOnSession();
});

var server = http.createServer(app);

var port = app.get('port');
server.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on port ' + port);

// Load server router
require('./router')(app);
```

EDIT 3:

Dashboard.vue

Here is the code that is already in place to redirect to the correct part of the app

```
getHelpNext() {
      var topic = this.pickedTopic;
      topic = topic.toLowerCase();
      var linkName = '/session/' + topic;
      this.$router.push(linkName);
    }
```

EDIT 4:

Router.js

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = function(app){
  console.log('Initializing server routing');

  require('./auth')(app);
  require('./api')(app);

  // Determine if incoming request is a static asset
  var isStaticReq = function(req){
    return ['/auth', '/api', '/js', '/css'].some(function(whitelist){
      return req.url.substr(0, whitelist.length) === whitelist;
    });
  };

  // Single page app routing
  app.use(function(req, res, next){
    if (isStaticReq(req)){
      return next();
    }
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'));
  });
};
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? I'm not seeing any code we can comment on?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make an endpoint that will get the request. This goes in express:

```
app.post('/some/end/point', (req, res) => {
  // -> send twillo message code here. If you use bodyParser,
  // req.body.message holds 'foo bar'
  res.status(200).end(); // do this if sending the message is a success
})
```

where app is your express server that listens on some port.
And this should go in your vue

```
this.$http.post('/some/end/point', {
  message: 'foo bar'
})
```

Comment: How would that work with this code that has already been implemented? I've added it to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing here several components that should be unit tested separately.

- Query Mongodb
- Node JS script - with mock of mongodb query result and not.
- Twillo text sending.
- UI test

Your question is probably referring to the last part but in order to properly implement it, you must break the unit test to these following topics.

As for UI test, there are many tools , my favourite is [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer).

Comment: I've been able to get the nodejs script to run on its own. I just don't know how to call it from the client side

Comment: Do you have endpoint for this service? using express. i.e. http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an endpoint on your server using `expressjs`, expose it to the internet and then call it from your client by doing a request.